# R: function to use search key from one df to identify values in a second df

Tags: r, lapply

I need to use the product codes listed in three columns from `search_key`:

```
search_key <- data.frame('product' = c('Apple', 'Apple', 'Apple', 'Banana', 
                                      'Banana', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Mango'),
                         'code' = c('123','000','232', '567', '222', '434',
                                    '999', '909'))
```

to identify specific products in `product_list`:

```
 product_list <- data.frame('code_1' = c('123','567','999'), 
                            'code_2' = c('000', '222', NA),
                            'code_3' = c('232', NA, NA),
                            'price' = c('1.29', '2.29', '3.24'))
```

to produce an end result of `final_list`:

```
   final_list <- data.frame('code_1' = c('123','567','999'), 
                            'code_2' = c('000', '222', NA),
                            'code_3' = c('232', NA, NA),
                            'price' = c('1.29', '2.29', '3.24'),
                            'product' = c('Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango'))
```

What function can I use to systematically search `product_list` using the codes from `search_key` to identify and create a "product" column in `final_list`? Thanks, in advance!

Comment: This is just a merge operation. `merge(product_list, search_key, by=paste0("code_",1:3))` - can I suggest taking a look at a site like http://www.statmethods.net/management/merging.html for getting some basics down-pat?

Comment: Assuming you want one output row for each row in `search_key` then this will perform the lookup by all common column names:   `merge(search_key, product_list, all.x = TRUE)`

Comment: You can start searching here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+merge+data.frame

Comment: Hi all, sorry for the confusion -- it looks like a dumbed down my toy example a little _too_ much. I've just made the appropriate edits above. The product codes are actually listed across multiple columns of `product_list`, whereas they are specified list wise in the `search_key`. I think I need some sort of grep function, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way for you. Seeing your final outcome, I think you want to rearrange `product_list`. I used `melt()` and converted your data in a long format. Then, merge with `search_key` with `code`.The final step is done by `spread()` in the `tidyr` package; the function converts a long format data to a wide format data.

```
library(magrittr)
library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)

melt(product_list, id.var = "price", value.name = "code") %>%
merge(search_key, by = "code") %>%
spread(key = "variable", value = "code")

#  product price code_1 code_2 code_3
#1   Apple  1.29    123    000    232
#2  Banana  2.29    567    222   <NA>
#3   Mango  3.24    999   <NA>   <NA>
```

Comment: Also, as you have used `tidyr`, `gather(product_list, variable, code, -price) %>% inner_join(.,search_key, by = "code") %>% spread(variable, code)`

Comment: @akrun Yep. You can stick to dplyr and tidyr for all operations. Thank you for the note as usual. :)

Comment: Thanks, @jazzurro, the melt function works great and makes a merge doable if I convert both DFs list wise!